# Android Xiaomi Redmi failed to start new process

Tags: android, process, synchronization, android-syncadapter

I have sync service which is running in a separate process

```
    <service
        android:name=".local_data.SyncService"
        android:exported="true"
        android:process=":sync">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
            android:resource="@xml/syncadapter" />
    </service>
```

On every phone it's starting new process successfully except the Xiaomi, in process picker I just see main process. I've tried to start my sync service in main process and it was working fine.

Comment: Than there must be something wrong with your code. Add service code here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't new on Xiaomi because Xiaomi has a feature called app permission, where user has to allow the app to start automatically (Service).

Go like this and allow your app to autostart:

`Settings > permissions > Autostart`

Answer (score 1):

You can problematically request auto-start permission by redirecting to autostart page in Xiaomi devices as follows:

```
void showAutoStartPermission(){
    String manufacturer = "xiaomi";
    if (manufacturer.equalsIgnoreCase(android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER)) { 
        //this will open auto start screen where user can enable permission for your app
        Intent intent1 = new Intent();
        intent1.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity"));
        startActivity(intent1);
    }
}
```